# Good Europe focused economics blogs

Tags: reference-request, financial-economics

Who can recommend any good blogs or other news sources on economics with a European view. I'm looking for something in the vein of FT, which is already an extremely good source, but I'd like to broaden my intake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a European view:

1. The [CEPR VOX EU](https://voxeu.org/): an economics blog created by the Centre for Economic Policy Research, which promotes research excellence and policy relevance in European economics. It covers a diverse range of research based analyses on policy and economic issues.
2. [The Economist](https://www.economist.com/) a global scope with a European perspective.
3. [EconomicsUK](http://www.economicsuk.com/blog/): personal website of The Sunday Times' Economics Editor. A perfect blog to learn about European economics.
4. [Alpha.sources](http://www.clausvistesen.com/alphasources-blog/): personal website of a Eurozone Economist. Covers macroeconomic issues.
5. [Thomas Piketty's Blog](http://piketty.blog.lemonde.fr/category/in-english/): Economist views on current social and political issues in France, Europe and the world.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add [Bruegel](http://bruegel.org/) which is an economics think tank with interesting insights.

The [economics department of the OECD](http://www.oecd.org/eco/)

The website [of the european commission](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/index_en).